# Microsoft excel formula on rounding up values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

If a value is less than 200, then it should be rounded up to 200.

How do you do this in Microsoft Excel?

Comment: Do you mean if the number is between 1 - 200, it should return 200? Then use =ceiling(A1,200) (where a1 is either your number or the reference cell). This will round all numbers up by 200, so 201 will be 400. If that's not what you meant, edit your question to give some example conditions.

Comment: if its more than 200, then it should be remain unchanged

Comment: I've created an overview of all answers given, so that you can see the result yourself: http://goo.gl/ryoYz

Answer (score 2):

Below formula helps

```
=MAX(A1, 200)
```

Comment: ok, updated....

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement:

- If a value is less than 200, then it should be round up to 200.
- if its more than 200, then it should be remain unchanged

**Solution:**

```
=MAX(200, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted everything under 200 rounded to 200, and everything else left alone:

> =IF(CELL<200, 200, CELL);

'CELL' being the coordinate.

If you literally wanted just the range from 1-200 to be rounded to 200, and not values less than 1, **as your original question specifies**:

> =IF(cell<200, IF(cell<1, cell, 200), cell)

This will satisfy your stated requirements.

Comment: sorry but if it's more than 200 then it should remain as is

Comment: Yes, and both of these formulas(formulae) do that.  Do a bit of work.